# Additional condition in Python list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How would you delete all starting empty items form a list using list comprehension **without** deleting empty elements in the middle of list. This is an example:

```
desc = []
desc.append('')
desc.append('')
desc.append('')
desc.append('line 1')
desc.append('line 2')
desc.append('')
desc.append('')
desc.append('line 3')
filtered = [x for x in desc if x]
filtered
['line 1', 'line 2', 'line 3']
```

Here is a simple list comprehension that **delete** all empty items:

```
filtered = [x for x in desc if x != '']
```

What I am trying to achieve using list comprehension is something similar to this:

```
for i in enumerate(desc):
    if desc[0].strip() == '':
        desc.pop(0)
```

Comment: this isn't really a list comprehension question, because you need to look at just the first element

Comment: you just want to delete first element of the list if it is empty ?

Comment: Yes, just the empty items at the start of the list. But I was thinking that might be possible using List comprehension.

Comment: List comprehensions are not suited to all tasks you would want to do with lists. Anything where one output depends on those before it is a job for an ordinary loop.

Comment: @user2357112 - have a look at Peter Wood's answer.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66: Note that that answer doesn't use a list comprehension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`itertools.dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile):

```
>>> from itertools import dropwhile

>>> lines = ['', '', 'line1', 'line2', '', '']
>>> list(dropwhile(lambda line: not line, lines))
['line1', 'line2', '', '']
```

Alternatively to the lambda, you could use [`operator.not_`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.not_), as @JonClements suggests:

```
>>> from operator import not_

>>> list(dropwhile(not_, lines))
['line1', 'line2', '', '']
```

Comment: Could also do `from operator import not_` then `list(dropwhile(not_, lines))`

Comment: This is what I call a brilliant solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> desc = ['', '', '  ', 'line 1', 'line 2', '', '', 'line 3']
>>> filtered = next(desc[i:] for i in range(len(desc)) if desc[i].strip())
>>> filtered
['line 1', 'line 2', '', '', 'line 3']
```

---

The built-in function `next` will only iterate till it finds `non empty element` in desc list. As soon it finds an element it will stop iteration and will return list from that element till the end instead of iterating `whole desc list`.

```
>>> help(next)
Help on built-in function next in module __builtin__:

next(...)
    next(iterator[, default])

    Return the next item from the iterator. If default is given and the iterator
    is exhausted, it is returned instead of raising StopIteration.
```

Comment: This will also delete the empty string at the middle of the list. I want them to remain. I just want to get red of the empty items at the first.

Answer (score 1):

Other solutions are good. If list comprehension is not necessary then maybe you can try this single line method,

```
>>> desc
['', '', '', 'line 1', 'line 2', '', '', 'line 3']
>>> 
>>> ';'.join(desc).lstrip(';').split(';')
['line 1', 'line 2', '', '', 'line 3']
>>>
```

Step 1 - Join all elements of the list by some delimiter

```
>>> x = ';'.join(desc)
';;;line 1;line 2;;;line 3'
```

Step 2 - Strip delimiters from the starting of the string

```
>>> x = x.lstrip(';')
'line 1;line 2;;;line 3'
```

Step 3 - Split the string on delimiter to get the output

```
>>> x.split(';')
['line 1', 'line 2', '', '', 'line 3']
```

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension is a nice way to write the creation of a result list only when the decision of which elements to include depend on properties of each sigle element itself.

If the condition depends on other factors (e.g. the position in the result) then probably an explicit loop is more readable instead (and readability is the main point of list comprehensions).

Examples of good use:

- all even numbers of a list
- all objects with a size bigger than a certain amount
- all not empty elements

Examples that don't fit well the comprehension concept:

- first five even number (NOT ok for a comprehension, the "first five" part doesn't depend on each single element)
- removing empty elements at the beginning of a list (the condition depends on other elements)
- unique elements, i.e. keeping only the first if an element appears multiple times (the decision about an element depends on previous decisions).

Of course you can try to abuse the comprehension to do things they were not designed for, but if the result code is less readable than just writing out the algorithm explicitly then there is no reason to do that.

Comment: but you could also use the itertools module and use dropwhile, as Peter Wood has demonstrated.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66: Like I said you can abuse comprehensions if you really like, but why doing that? Remember that readability is the main point. Of course for example separating the problem of "first five even numbers" into "first five" and "even numbers" is ok for readability and is also ok for performance with generators (but with comprehensions it would extract all even numbers to keep only first five and that may be a bad idea).

Comment: I don't consider using the standard library like itertools etc to be abusing comprehensions.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66: That answer is not using list comprehensions at all.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can just translate what you wrote into list comprehensions

```
filtered = desc[:]
crap = [filtered.pop(0) for i in filtered if filtered[0].strip()==""]
```